# Stuck in Emergency mode after update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04, boot-repair, disk-management

my system is stuck in Emergency mode and giving me this error, i have Ubuntu on ssd drive and windows on hdd drive.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Try this..

```
startx
```

if not working then use

```
apt install xserver-xorg-legacy
sudo Xorg -configure
startx
```

Comment: That works for me when the system not loading properly